# com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: i/o failure

Tags: android-studio, parse-platform, parse-server

I just installed nodejs mongodb and parse-server on a ubuntu server. when I'm trying to use the server it gives this error :
com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: i/o failure

When I'm using curl GET and POST I can totally access and change data but not doable in android studio. I have added the parse-server on gradle build and also added permissions on manifest

```
Parse.initialize(
        Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
            .server("http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1337/parse/")
            .applicationId("myAppId")
            .build()
    )
    val parseInventory = ParseObject("Inventory")
    parseInventory.put("cheatMode",false)
    parseInventory.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. just in case someone in the future face same issue :

it's a security problem. you need to add the IP address you are trying to access into the manifest like this : inside xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <network-security-config>
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">X.XXX.XXX.XXX</domain>
</domain-config>
    </network-security-config>
```

and then this one inside manifest:

```
            android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/security"
```

the reason is that you dont have https! I believe if you get SSL on the server it would be fine

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. For me solution was adding to AndroidManifest:

```
<application
...
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
>
```

But your option is working more precisely.

The cause of the problem is that "android:usesCleartextTraffic" default is false.